# How to identify and highlight outliers in each row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I want to do the following to my dataframe:

1. For each row identify outliers/anomalies
2. Highlight/color the identified outliers' cells (preferably 'red' color)
3. Count the number of identified outliers in each row  (store in a column 'anomaly_count')
4. Export the output as an `xlsx` file

See below for sample data

```
np.random.seed([5, 1591])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.normal(size=(16,5)),
    columns=list('ABCDE')
)

df

        A            B          C         D            E
0   -1.685112   -0.432143   0.876200    1.626578    1.512677
1   0.401134    0.439393    1.027222    0.036267    -0.655949
2   -0.074890   0.312793    -0.236165   0.660909    0.074468
3   0.842169    2.759467    0.223652    0.432631    -0.484871
4   -0.619873   -1.738938   -0.054074   0.337663    0.358380
5   0.083653    0.792835    -0.643204   1.182606    -1.207692
6   -1.168773   -1.456870   -0.707450   -0.439400   0.319728
7   2.316974    -0.177750   1.289067    -2.472729   -1.310188
8   2.354769    1.099483    -0.653342   -0.532208   0.269307
9   0.431649    0.666982    0.361765    0.419482    0.531072
10  -0.124268   -0.170720   -0.979012   -0.410861   1.000371
11  -0.392863   0.933516    -0.502608   -0.759474   -1.364289
12  1.405442    -0.297977   0.477609    -0.046791   -0.126504
13  -0.711799   -1.042558   -0.970183   -1.672715   -0.524283
14  0.029966    -0.579152   0.648176    0.833141    -0.942752
15  0.824767    0.974580    0.363170    0.428062    -0.232174
```

The desired outcome should look something like this:

```
## I want to ONLY identify the outliers NOT remove or substitute them. I only used NaN to depict the outlier value. Ideally, the outlier values cell should be colored/highlighted 'red'.

## Please note:  the outliers NaN in the sample are randomly assigned.

 
        A            B          C         D            E      Anomaly_Count
0     NaN     -0.432143     0.876200         NaN  1.512677        2
1   0.401134    0.439393    1.027222    0.036267    -0.655949     0
2   -0.074890   0.312793    -0.236165   0.660909    0.074468      0
3   0.842169    NaN         0.223652    0.432631    -0.484871     1
4   -0.619873   -1.738938   -0.054074   0.337663    0.358380      0
5   0.083653    0.792835    -0.643204    NaN           NaN        2
6   -1.168773   -1.456870   -0.707450   -0.439400   0.319728      0
7   2.316974    -0.177750   1.289067    -2.472729   -1.310188     0
8   2.354769    1.099483    -0.653342   -0.532208   0.269307      0
9   0.431649    0.666982    0.361765    0.419482    0.531072      0
10  -0.124268   -0.170720   -0.979012   -0.410861   NaN           1
11  -0.392863   0.933516    -0.502608   -0.759474   -1.364289     0
12  1.405442    -0.297977   0.477609    -0.046791   -0.126504     0
13  -0.711799   -1.042558   -0.970183   -1.672715   -0.524283     0
14  0.029966    -0.579152   0.648176    0.833141    -0.942752     0
15  0.824767    NaN        0.363170     0.428062    -0.232174     1
```

See below for my attempt, I am open to other approaches

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

def outlier_detection (data):
      # step I: identify the outliers in each row
      df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis = 0)]  # unfortunately this removes the outliers which I dont want
      # step II: color/highlight the outlier cell 
      df = df.style.highlight_null('red')
      # Step III: count the number of outliers in each row 
      df['Anomaly_count'] = df.isnull().sum(axis=1)
      # step IV: export as xlsx file
      df.to_excel(r'Path to store the exported excel file\File Name.xlsx', sheet_name='Your sheet name', index = False)
      


outlier_detection(df)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What's exactly your criteria for outlier? `np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3` is `True` everywhere.

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't have a predefined criterion. How would you go about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed([5, 1591])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.normal(size=(16, 5)),
    columns=list('ABCDE')
)


mask = pd.DataFrame(abs(stats.zscore(df)) > 1, columns=df.columns)
df["Count"] = mask.sum(axis=1)
mask["Count"] = False
style_df = mask.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: red" if x else "")

sheet_name = "Values"
with pd.ExcelWriter("score_test.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    df.style.apply(lambda x: style_df, axis=None).to_excel(writer, 
                                                           sheet_name=sheet_name,
                                                           index=False)
```

Here the mask is the boolean conditional where we have true if zscore exceeds the limit. Based on this boolean mask I create a string dataframe 'style_df' with the values 'background: red' on the deviating cells. The values of the style_df is imposed with the last statement on the style of the df dataframe.

The resulting excel file looks now like this
[image: contents of excel file]

Comment: This works fine.  (1) Can you explain the rationale behind `zscore_limit = 1`? (2)  I think you forgot to count the outliers in each row `anomaly_count` column. (3),can you highlight ONLY the outliers 'red'.  Lastly, please can you confirm the outliers are identified row-wise ( and not column-wise just to be sure) in the `score_test.xlsx` ?. Thanks alot

Comment: Just updated the example. The idea of having a parameter zscore_limit = 1 was that you can modify this parameter from outside, however, it did not work because you are not allowed to pass any arguments to the apply function. I have therefore dropped it. Also, I have reorganized the code a bit to match your question

Comment: Also I am using lambda functions now to make it a bit shorted

Comment: @ Eelco. Thanks for yesterday's script works like magic!.